# Authentication issue - Azure REST API called from azure functions

Tags: node.js, rest, active-directory, azure-functions, azure-synapse

I am working on azure functions to call the rest API of Azure SQL datawarehouse to pause and resume the server( 2 functions)at specific times during the day. In the azure functions that I created before I never had to call the REST API as I used only the available output options. Whereas SQL DW has only REST API option.

I create a function app with nodejs and from there I am calling these REST APIs. I went through the [azure REST API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/) and tried the process explained there. 
First I add the function app as a tenant in the azure active directory and got the tenantID( it is there part of the endpoint urls) and the application ID / client ID and then tried to call the login URL as mentioned here  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#request-an-authorization-code
by passing the required parameters.Though it is mentioned as GET I tried both GET and POST and they did not work.

```
module.exports = function(context) {
var unirest = require('unirest');

var subscriptionId='subscriptionId';
context.log("starting the function");
unirest.post('https://login.windows.net/tenantID/oauth2/authorize')
.headers({'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
.send({ "client_id": "clientID ", "response_type": "code","grant_type":"authorization_code" })
.end(function (response) {
  context.log(response.body);
});
});
```

This code piece is just for getting the auth code and then there will be one more method to get the token and then to call the actual SQL DW pause/resume method. 
When I run the same from VS2015 ( removed the module exports and change context to console)I get the same error as below

```
<html><head><title>Continue</title></head><body><form method="POST" name="hiddenform" action="https://login.microsoftonline.com/9b8d9cda-ddb4-43bb-8725-bc0e9af83b43/oauth2/authorize"><noscript><p>Script is disabled. Click Submit to continue</p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></noscript></form><script language="javascript">window.setTimeout('document.forms[0].submit()', 0);</script></body></html>
```

I am not sure what I am missing here. If anyone had done it before do share your comments/ solutions.

Update: adding the Azure AD - registration permissions page as reply to one of the comments. Let me know if this one is as per the requirements. 
[image]

I found the issue with respect to the permissions. I had to provide the SQL Database server manager RBAC role to the app in the AAD. 
The Resume commandlet worked fine but the Suspend commandlet did not work . The following exception occurred.

> Suspend-AzureRmSqlDatabase : 40640: The server encountered an unexpected exception.
>   At line:9 char:35
>   +     $resultDatabase = $database | Suspend-AzureRmSqlDatabase;
>   +                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Suspend-AzureRmSqlDatabase], CloudException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.DatabaseActivation.Cmdlet.SuspendAzureSqlDatabase

Comment: Should the post not be to https://login.microsoftonline.com and not login.windows.net for getting the first access_token. I see in the docs that login.windows.net is suggested only once you have a token to access the resource for auth

Comment: yeah.. my bad.. thanks for spotting that. let me change and try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you be open to using PowerShell in Functions to achive the same results?  Azure SQL Data Warehouse (DW) has [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-reference-powershell-cmdlets) commands that allow you to Pause and Resume the Azure SQL DW.  Using PowerShell seems to be easier compared to crafting the HTTP request and processing the HTTP response.

The following are steps on how to create HTTP-triggered PowerShell Functions to **Pause** and **Resume** an Azure SQL DW. You may re-create a Timer-triggered PowerShell Function with the same `run.ps1` files.

1. Setup a service principal to obtain the username, password and tenant id.  It is a one-time task and I feel that it is worth it to leverage running Azure PowerShell in Functions.  There are many docs online, but here are some links to documents on how to setup your service principal:

   i. http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/12/azure-service-principal.html (I used this one)

   ii. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal
2. Log into the Functions portal to access your Function app.
3. Click on **Function app settings->Configure app settings** and add the key-value pairs for the settings `SP_USERNAME`, `SP_PASSWORD`, and `TENANTID` (You may use other desired key names).
4. Create an HTTP-triggered PowerShell Function named, e.g. **SuspendSqlDataWarehouse** with the following content in its `run.ps1` file.

```
    $requestBody = Get-Content $req -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

    # Set Service Principal credentials
    # SP_PASSWORD, SP_USERNAME, TENANTID are app settings
    $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $env:SP_PASSWORD -AsPlainText -Force;
    $mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($env:SP_USERNAME, $secpasswd)
    Add-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $env:TENANTID -Credential $mycreds;
    $context = Get-AzureRmContext;
    Set-AzureRmContext -Context $context;

    # Suspend SQL Data Warehouse
    $database = Get-AzureRmSqlDatabase –ResourceGroupName $requestBody.resourcegroup –ServerName $requestBody.server –DatabaseName $requestBody.databasename
    if($database.Status -ne "Paused") # IF-condition added on 2/3/2017 
    {
        $resultDatabase = $database | Suspend-AzureRmSqlDatabase;
        $resultDatabase | Out-String;
    }
```

5. Click on the **Save** button.
6. Next, click on the **Logs** button to open the log viewer.
7. Click on the **Test** button to open the simple HTTP client.  In the request body, provide the resourcegroup, server and databasename values for the SQL DW, e.g.

```
    {
       "resourcegroup": "testresourcegroup",
       "server": "testserver",
       "databasename" : "testsqldw"
    }
```

8. Click on the **Run** button and wait for a few seconds.  It takes some time (~3-4 mins) for the `Get-AzureRmSqlDatabase` and `Suspend-AzureRmSqlDatabase` cmdlet to run to completion.  When it does, you should see similar entries in the log viewer.

```
    2016-12-09T18:02:07.990 Function started (Id=3c270254-f935-4a32-8b27-13131b6257d4)
    2016-12-09T18:02:09.224 Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.PSAzureContext
    2016-12-09T18:02:09.224 Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.PSAzureContext
    2016-12-09T18:03:25  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).
    2016-12-09T18:04:25  No new trace in the past 2 min(s).
    2016-12-09T18:05:11.787 ResourceGroupName             : testresourcegroup
    ServerName                    : testserver
    DatabaseName                  : testsqldw
    Location                      : West US
    DatabaseId                    : [some guid]
    Edition                       : DataWarehouse
    CollationName                 : SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    CatalogCollation              : 
    MaxSizeBytes                  : 10995116277760
    Status                        : Paused
    CreationDate                  : 12/9/2016 5:14:35 PM
    CurrentServiceObjectiveId     : [some guid]
    CurrentServiceObjectiveName   : DW400
    RequestedServiceObjectiveId   : [some guid]
    RequestedServiceObjectiveName : 
    ElasticPoolName               : 
    EarliestRestoreDate           : 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
    Tags                          : 
    ResourceId                    : /subscriptions/[some guid]
                                    /resourceGroups/testresourcegroup/providers
                                    /Microsoft.Sql/servers/testserver/databases/tests
                                    qldw
    CreateMode                    :
    2016-12-09T18:05:11.787 Function completed (Success, Id=3c270254-f935-4a32-8b27-13131b6257d4)
```

9. Repeat steps 4-8 to create the **ResumeSqlDataWarehouse** Function with the following content in its `run.ps1` file.

```
    $requestBody = Get-Content $req -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

    # Set Service Principal credentials
    # SP_PASSWORD, SP_USERNAME, TENANTID are app settings
    $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $env:SP_PASSWORD -AsPlainText -Force;
    $mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($env:SP_USERNAME, $secpasswd)
    Add-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $env:TENANTID -Credential $mycreds;
    $context = Get-AzureRmContext;
    Set-AzureRmContext -Context $context;

    # Resume SQL Data Warehouse
    $database = Get-AzureRmSqlDatabase –ResourceGroupName $requestBody.resourcegroup –ServerName $requestBody.server –DatabaseName $requestBody.databasename
    $resultDatabase = $database | Resume-AzureRmSqlDatabase;
    $resultDatabase | Out-String;
```

The log entries would be similar to the following:

```
    2016-12-09T18:17:34.625 Function started (Id=55f6d69e-a32e-4153-89c8-e821c4429421)
    2016-12-09T18:17:36.504 Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.PSAzureContext
    2016-12-09T18:17:36.504 Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.PSAzureContext
    2016-12-09T18:18:07.836 ResourceGroupName             : testresourcegroup
    ServerName                    : testserver
    DatabaseName                  : testsqldw
    Location                      : West US
    DatabaseId                    : [some guid]
    Edition                       : DataWarehouse
    CollationName                 : SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    CatalogCollation              : 
    MaxSizeBytes                  : 10995116277760
    Status                        : Online
    CreationDate                  : 12/9/2016 5:14:35 PM
    CurrentServiceObjectiveId     : [some guid]
    CurrentServiceObjectiveName   : DW400
    RequestedServiceObjectiveId   : [some guid]
    RequestedServiceObjectiveName : 
    ElasticPoolName               : 
    EarliestRestoreDate           : 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
    Tags                          : 
    ResourceId                    : /subscriptions/[some guid]
                                    /resourceGroups/testresourcegroup/providers/
                                    Microsoft.Sql/servers/testserver/databases/tests
                                    qldw
    CreateMode                    :
    2016-12-09T18:18:07.836 Function completed (Success, Id=55f6d69e-a32e-4153-89c8-e821c4429421)
```

**Note:** I noticed that it takes a few minutes to suspend a SQL Data Warehouse.  In the current release of Azure Functions, all Functions have a maximum execution time of 5 minutes.  It is alright if your Function executes the **Pause/Resume** command before the 5 minutes as the task itself will get kicked off.  You may just write another Function to poll for the status of the SQL Data Warehouse until you get expected `Paused/Online` value.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the powershell option. Can I configure this as a Time trigger and put the values in the script itself instead of this http trigger?

Comment: Yes, you can recreate these as Timer triggers. As for the values, you can hard-code it into the script itself. Otherwise for a better security model, you can also add it to the app settings just as the sample did for the service principal username, password and tenant id.

Comment: After not getting the authorization working with the REST API option I tried the powershell option that you shared. I got the following error. Resume-AzureRmSqlDatabase : AuthorizationFailed: The client '2a4f65b9-1a93-4294-bd37-72a2df4a7843' with object id 
'2a4f65b9-1a93-4294-bd37-72a2df4a7843' does not have authorization to perform action.. I have not seen this client ID anywhere. I had given all the right client, app id in the function app settings. not sure of this.

Comment: @Aravind, can you make sure that your service principal was given full rights at the subscription level?  Also, from this thread, it seems that some folks said the service principal setup works when done through Portal UI instead of through PowerShell. https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli/issues/2051

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the azure AD app registration permissions page. Could you tell me what needs to changed here or if it is somewhere else..?

Comment: Seems like you may be experiencing permissions issue accessing your SQL DW resource.  Are you able to run the same commands from a PowerShell console on your dev machine?  If you see the same error, then it is very likely a permissions issue.  Do you have administrative privileges on the SQL DW?

Comment: I get the same error in powershell too. I created the SQL DW in my azure subscription ( login via microsoft live id). But am wondering if the function app needs administrative privileges to pause and resume. Not sure how to go about that.

Comment: If you are seeing the same error when executing the command from a PowerShell console on your dev machine, then it's a very likely a permissions issue between your subscription and SQL DW.   I am not too familiar with SQL DW.  Would it be possible for you to contact SQL DW team to figure out how to resolve this?  Then try it on your local dev machine first before attempting in Function app.

Comment: I found this documentation to set AD admin  properties to SQL DB/ DW but when I browse to the portal I do not see this setting in the sql DW that i created https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication#4-create-an-azure-ad-administrator-for-azure-sql-server

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to repro the error.  I suggest that you create a support ticket with SQL DW, explaining that you are unable to run these cmdlets in the PowerShell console on your dev machine.  Here is the link to SQL DW's support portal:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-get-started-create-support-ticket

Once the you are able to execute the cmdlets in your own env, retry in your Function app and it should work. Otherwise, feel free to update this thread.  I will be monitor this thread and look forward to your good news.

Comment: actually even the active directory admin applies only to users and not apps registered in AAD.

Comment: I have updated the question. The Resume command worked fine. But the suspend command failed with an exception ( I have added in the question) The error message does not really show more details though.

Comment: I just retried the Suspend cmdlet and it worked fine for me.  Make sure that you are running as admin on the PowerShell console in your dev machine and that you have the latest Azure PowerShell installed.  If it still does not work, and since there is no further info in the error message, you may contact SQL DW support to see if they can help troubleshoot.

Comment: Ah, I was able to repro the error you are seeing with Suspend after all.  You are right, the error message is not very helpful, but the issue is due to the fact that the Suspend cmdlet is run when the VM is already suspended.  To fix this, place an IF condition around the Suspend cmdlet, e.g. if($database.Status -ne "Paused") so that the cmdlet only executes when the VM status is not already suspended.